# Fileconveyor Installation

Tags: python, drupal-6, cdn, cloudfiles

With Fileconveyor limited documentation I'm confused as to where it installs after I've run the pip command as follows on their website Fileconveyor.org.

Bottom line: Anyone have luck installing Fileconveyor on Debian 6 for integration with Drupal 6 and the CND Module?

I can't figure out where to put my settings.xml file.

Thanks,
Curtis

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does give indication of where things are put, but it isn't entirely clear in that we expect an "installation" to move things to certain destinations, such as /usr/bin. In reality, Fileconveyor is installed in the very same directory as wherever the git clone placed it.

The settings file (which must be cp from a file named "config.sample.xml") is in a folder 'conveyor' within the main 'conveyor' folder.

The link where you can read about this is https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor

It reads in part: "The sample configuration file (config.sample.xml) should be self explanatory. Copy this file to config.xml, which is the file File Conveyor will look for,
and edit it to suit your needs."

Starting it doesn't actually invoke any command with the name 'fileconveyor', which I previously mentioned is what one might expect from a typical installation. Another instruction from the above link reads:

### "Starting File Conveyor

File Conveyor must be started by starting its arbitrator (which links
everything together; it controls the file system monitor, the processor
chains, the transporters and so on). You can start the arbitrator like this:
  python /path/to/fileconveyor/arbitrator.py"

In my case the command is 'python ~/src/conveyor/conveyor/arbitrator.py'

In retrospect I might reinstall in another directory in case I ever empty my ~/src folder which is the folder I use to initially download items to compile and install, then clean. I wasn't expecting it to end up being the installation folder for Fileconveyor.

Hope this helps.